# ant rpm task - command not found on %prep

Tags: linux, rpm

I have been asked to make RPM packages for our OPS team to install our software. I found that ant had an RPM task and started to use that. I populated a spec file based on [this link](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-build-creating-spec-file.html), [this one](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/RPM-HOWTO/build.html) and [also this one](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/ch-rpm-b-command.html) . However I have now reached an impasse. I keep getting "[rpm] : command not founderror: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.VNmA3k (%prep)" from the RPM task.

I used RPMBUILD, and got exactly the same error, except /var/tmp/rpm-tmp. has a different file extension each time. If I go to that file on line 36 , I found "^M". Now this file seems to be generated by the RPMBUILD tool, so I have now control over it.

What am I doing wrong?

Spec File:

```
Name:   SYJBoss7
Version:        1.0
Release:        1
Summary:        Esentially a JBoss 7.1 release from the SwitchYard team, with custom modules for genvods

Group:          <our group name>
License:        none
URL:            none
Source0: file:///tmp/SYJBoss7.tar.gz
BuildRoot:      %(mktemp -ud %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-XXXXXX)

%description


%prep
%setup -q


%build
pwd

%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/swithcyard/

install -s SYJboss7 $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/swithcyard/


%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}


%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%doc
$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/swithcyard/


%changelog
```

Output from ant rpm command:

```
  [rpm] Building the RPM based on the example.spec file
  [rpm] Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.VNmA3k
  [rpm] + umask 022
  [rpm] + cd /tmp/rpm/SYJboss7/BUILD
  [rpm] + cd /tmp/rpm/SYJboss7/BUILD
  [rpm] + rm -rf SYJBoss7-1.0
  [rpm] + /bin/tar -xf -
  [rpm] + /usr/bin/gzip -dc /tmp/rpm/SYJboss7/SOURCES/SYJBoss7.tar.gz
  [rpm] + STATUS=0
  [rpm] + '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
  [rpm] + cd SYJBoss7-1.0
  [rpm] + /bin/chmod -Rf a+rX,u+w,g-w,o-w .
  [rpm] + $'\r'
  [rpm] /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.VNmA3k: line 36: 
  [rpm] : command not founderror: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.VNmA3k (%prep)
  [rpm]     Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.VNmA3k (%prep)
  [rpm] 
  [rpm] 
  [rpm] RPM build errors:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the sign `$'\r'` (Carriage Return) has no line-ending meaning in Linux. So yuo better leave it out; it will mess up your scripts.

Probably you (or someone else) edited this `.spec` file with a Windows editor.

Look at the `%prep` section and try to fix the erroneous line endings with your favourite editor.